# C# ListView Last Column Too Wide

Tags: c#, listview, width, autoresize

When a list view's 'AutoResizeColumns(...)' method is called with either 'None' or 'ColumnContent' as parameters the last column does not expand to fill the entire panel, however if 'AutoResizeColumns(...)' is called with 'HeaderSize' as a parameter the last column is expanded, which looks odd if your text is centre or right aligned.

I've been able to fix this issue by adding an extra blank column a the end to expand and contract as necessary, leaving my intended last column to just cover the width of the heading but this seems a bit hackie.  Is their a neater way to do it?

Thanks.

[Last Column Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO5kM.png)

[Preferred Width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfv6X.png)

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem. this seems to happen to the column with the last DisplayIndex. so you could add a dummy column before resizing and remove it afterwards:

```
        var dummy = new ColumnHeader();

        // dummy gets the last DisplayIndex
        listView1.Columns.Add(dummy);
        // dummy gets the remaining space instead
        listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
        listView1.Columns.Remove(dummy);
```

alternatively, you could change the DisplayIndex of the last column, then call AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize) on this last column, and then restore it's DisplayIndex

Answer (score 1):

One solution I've found is to temporarily reduce the size of the ListView, call 'AutoResizeColumns(...)' then reset the size of the List View

As in:

    `int listViewWidth = listView1.Width;
    listView1.Width = 0;
    listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    listView1.Width = listViewWidth;`

This seems a bit hackie but at least it doesn't a add a superfluous column.

Comment: i have the same problem, but this didn't work for me unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

The ColumnHeader can be set to adjust at run time to the column contents or heading. You can do this by setting the width property to -2 (To autosize the width of the column)

OR

ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)

Comment: Yes, I am currently using ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize) however this expands the last column to fill the available space.  See the pictures I've just added.

I also tried setting the width to -2 but this seemed to expand whichever colons I set the width on to fill the window even if it wasn't the last column.

Comment: You can do one this for this, Set Width of Listview first Say 600,
Then Set Width of each header Column as said earlier

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand.  Are you saying if I were to set the width of the ListView itself the last column will stop expanding to fill the space?  That seems very unlikely but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Setting Width to listview and then to column headers to fit in your listview

Comment: I think we might be describing different things.  It is just the width of the last column I am wanting to prevent from expanding.  The size of the ListView itself is fine.  I would just prefer for their to be blank space to the right of the last column than for the last column to be expanded to fill the entire ListView.  I can't pre-determine the width of the columns, nor even how many columns there are going to be, I just want that last column to only be as wide as it needs to be (like all the other columns) and not to automatically expand to fill the remainder of the ListView.

Comment: May be this can help
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3239/Autosize-the-last-column-in-a-ListView-control-usi

Comment: Something that does work though is to temporarly set the width of the ListView to 0, call ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize), then reset the size of the ListView.  I can't format text in there so will give an example as another answer.